# Error 500.31 after deployed ASP.NET Core 3.1 app to Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-core

I tried to deploy ASP.NET Core 3.1 to azure app service from VS 2019:

[image]

and I got:

[image]

I cannot install .net core in that machine because I created app service (windows)

[image]

I tried with Self-contained with win-64

[image]

But i got a lot of errors:

[image]

What should do ?

Comment: Use `dotnet publish` command line to publish self contained binaries.

Comment: How to run publish command when I used one from VS? Should use that command and then copy files to that service manually ?

Comment: `https://{site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net` add `scm` after sitename and check the logs

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I tried to open that url or via Kudu, it asks me for credentials. I think that I don’t have permission or ... I don’t know else

Comment: Can you go to your Azure Portal, and your App Service? From there, Settings > Configuration > General settings. Try to change the stack to .NET, ASP.NET v4.7 and restart the web app. If it does not work, try the stack .NET Core

Comment: I have .Net Core stack selected